# Creating a procedure that inserts into 2 tables with a relationship

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I understand that there is a lot of questions like this one but as it is for my school project it needs to follow the same techniques that they have taught us and the other answers aren't quite what i'm looking for.

My code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE add_hire1 (hire_no_in IN NUMBER, date_hired_in IN DATE, drop_off_in IN DATE, fk1_customer_id_in IN NUMBER, fk2_charge_no_in IN NUMBER,
charge_no_in, final_cost_in)
AS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO hire(hire_no, date_hired, drop_off, fk1_customer_id, fk2_charge_no)
VALUES (hire_no_in, date_hired_in, drop_off_in, fk1_customer_id_in, fk2_charge_no_in);

 INSERT INTO charge(charge_no, final_cost)
 VALUES(charge_no_in, final_cost_in);
END add_hire1;
```

This is the error returned:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 590 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 576
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2033
```

As we have just been taught how to do it with one table I have just added the second table in the same format as the original code so I'm not sure if it's correct or if there's just a few small errors.
Any help appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: Your last 2 parameters `charge_no_in, final_cost_in` need a data type e.g. `NUMBER`.

Comment: And reading the docs and syntax is a good idea as well: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/procedure.htm#LNPLS01336.

Answer (score 2):

ORA-24344 signifies **compilation errors**. If you are using a tool like SQL Developer it should show you the compilation errors. But you can always find them for yourself like this:

```
select * from user_errors
where name = 'ADD_HIRE1'
```

If we had a package which compiled then we changed it and now it doesn't compile we know we need to focus on the changes we made. In this case we can see that the two parameters you've just added …

```
,
charge_no_in, final_cost_in)
AS
```

… are not declared in the same way as the other parameters:

```
, fk1_customer_id_in IN NUMBER, fk2_charge_no_in IN NUMBER
```

That difference is a big clue as to how you need to fix your code.